# If other animals evolved to have similar anatomy to humans, would those with dewclaws end up with four or five fingers?

Tags: biology, evolution, fauna, anatomy, humanoid

I’m writing a story about anthropomorphic animals who are their world’s equivalent of humans. They walk upright, talk, and have established a society, but I’m having trouble figuring out the anatomy of their hands (for the ones that have them). They’re meant to have similar anatomy to humans, but with their species’ characteristics added. For example, a dog in this world is the same general size and shape as a human, stands plantigrade, and can use their paws to pick things up and do anything a human can. Where I’m stuck is figuring out how many fingers the dog would have. Would only their four toes evolve into fingers, or would the dewclaw become a thumb and leave them with five?

Thank you for any help! It might seem dumb but this really has me stumped haha.

Comment: This seems like a classic “it’s up to you” situation.

Comment: Evolutionary considerations aside, a thumb-less hand will not allow these creatures to "do anything a human can". If you want human-level dexterity, you pretty much need the thumb.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie  That’s honestly a really good point! Don’t know why I didn’t realize that haha

Comment: this entirely depends on the path evolution takes, it is entirely possible the small digit would evolved in ot a thumb, or one of the other digits could, they could even end up with a chameleon like grip and two thumbs.

Comment: @John I was actually wondering about that! Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read "[The Panda's Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Panda%27s_Thumb_(book))" (but see also [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2017.21300) ... they evolved *twice*!).  A dewclaw serves some thumb-like roles, but it is entirely possible to develop a new sort of digit instead.  Note the people voting to close are saying that such issues are beyond science - because unimaginative assertions are what close voters *do*.

Comment: @Mike Serfas  Oh that’s actually really interesting! I’ll definitely read more on that because that’s pretty much exactly what I was wondering. Thank you for linking those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say the dew claw does that, it was obviously a digit in the past.

But you do not need thumbs, that is a myth. Elephants are wonderfully dexterous with their trunk; they can pick up one dime off of a stack of dimes. They can draw fine lines with a paintbrush held in their trunk.

Octopi are also dexterous, arguably more than humans: their suckers let them hold large or heavy objects without any handles. I know I am not that dexterous with a bowling ball without finger holes.

Crows are pretty dexterous with their beak; more so than with their clawed feet. That said, their feet have an opposable thumb; but there are only four digits: three forward facing, one backward facing. They often carry things in their feet during flight, but do not use their feet like hands when on the ground; sometimes they will hold something while they work on it with their beak.

I think when animals become intelligent enough, they figure out how to use what they've got to get the job done. If they don't have opposable thumbs they will just invent their devices and tools differently than we did.

Lots of disabled people manage to use tools while missing a thumb. I wouldn't underestimate the power of intelligence in finding solutions.

Comment: Meh, "can" and "can easily" are not the same thing.  This is like saying because some people can play the piano with their feet, there's no real advantage to having fingers.

Comment: @Jedediah I don't recall saying "can easily". Nor did I say there is no real advantage to having thumbs, so my answer is nothing like that. But yes, we can invent musical instruments we can play without thumbs, and handles that work to keep objects firmly in our grasp without thumbs. Where's this negativity coming from? Do you have some cherished notion about the paramount importance of thumbs?

Comment: Negativity?  I thought "meh" was more dismissive.

Comment: @Jedediah The negativity is in the piano simile which is hyperbolically incorrect.

Comment: You think I'm reading in by the "can" vs. "can easily" inference.  I think you're reading in with the "negativity" inference (and that you're actively negatively framing with "the cherished notion about the paramount importance of...").

Comment: @Jedediah You specifically wrote that "can" and "can easily" are not the same thing. This suggests you think "can easily" is important. And yes, I am actively negatively framing with "the cherished notion", because I regard that notion as hogwash; I do not think thumbs are of paramount importance to the development of anything. Dexterity or Intelligence. Dolphins are highly intelligent without either hands or feet. And once human level intelligence evolves (which is the underlying premise of this question) then the organism will invent tools to fit its anatomy.

Comment: Of course "can easily" is important.  Someone without legs can ascend a staircase.  Someone without hands can play the piano.  Some evolved animal which "can use their paws to pick things up and do anything a human can"...  It matters whether it *can* be done, or can easily be done.

Comment: I'll bite, though - what kind of tools would a dolphin with human-like intelligence (if they don't already have it) invent to, well, do much of anything besides swim and catch fish with their mouths?

Comment: @Jedediah Dolphins already make tools out of sponges with their mouths, and use them to brush the sea floor to stir up food which they catch. Their mouth is the equivalent of a hand; they can hold things with it. They don't but could shape shells or bones by grinding them against stone, to make blades, or spears. They could move stones, or plant and farm. if I were mobile, fast and strong with just one gripping hand, with my human intelligence, I imagine over thousands of years and millions like me we'd build shelters and hundreds of useful tools. We could *cooperate* to have multiple hands.

Comment: Huh.  That's interesting.  I'd be skeptical of the grinding bone or shell idea, though...  A bird might use its beak somewhat like a hand - but a bird has a flexible neck.  A dolphin trying to do fine work with its mouth as a hand would be kind of like a person trying to do fine work while having their wrist, elbow, and shoulder locked.